# Looping through each textboxes and inserting to MS SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, insert, textbox

Is there a method where I can loop this?

```
conn.ConnectionString = datapathdebug
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MS_SQLConnect SET 
            dbname=@dbname,
            sip=@dbip,
            sport=@dbport,
            uname=@uname,
            pwd=@pwd
            WHERE ID=@ID"
            **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dbname", txtdbname.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dbip", txtdbip.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dbport", txtdbport.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uname", txtdbusername.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pwd", txtdbpassword.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", txtid.Text)**
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been updated")
            Refresh()
            ShowItems()
            conn.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
```

I am also new to programming. Trying to find a way how if this can be tidy up a bit.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could modify that code to use a loop but it would be pointless as it would make the code barely, if at all, shorter and certainly not improve the readability.  What you're currently doing is the most appropriate option.

Comment: Hey jmcilhinney! Thank you for replying! Ohhh I see! That's a breather. If I were to INSERT/UPDATE and having to do like 20 of them then should I loop or it'll remain appropriate as it is? Thank you!

Comment: I would tend to put all the data into a `DataTable` and save it all in a batch with a single call to `Update` on a data adapter.

Comment: Hey jmcilhinney! Thank you so much for your help! But may you be so kind to set me an example on how to code the data into a DataTable and save it all in a batch all? I appreciate it alot. OFF TOPIC: Also, I was able to check a few forums and I seem to find your name in some of it!